# Ubuntu 20.04 Wayland is logging me out

Tags: gnome, wayland, logout

My setup is 20.04 with vanilla Gnome 3.36.2 on Wayland.  I previously ran 19.10 with the same setup.  `/` and `/home` are on separate filesystems.  I did a clean install of 20.04 onto `/` but maintained my home directory.

I am set up so that my screen blanks after 2 minutes and locks automatically after 5 minutes.  This worked fine under 19.10.

Under 20.04, when I return to my machine, I frequently find that I have been logged out rather than simply the screen lock.  This is very frustrating as I lose all open windows.  It happens around 50% of the time but not always.  Of course I can't tell if it's logging me out at the point of the screen lock or later (or earlier even) as the screen is blank.

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this or where I might look for some logging to find out what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there .crash files in /var/crash?

Comment: Yes.  There's a file called `_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash` full of useful (?) information.  I have no idea how to make use of it though.

Comment: The .crash file means it's not a *logout*; it's a *crash*, which is a bug. The .crash file contains the information needed for a Gnome developer to understand exactly what crashed and why.  If Ubuntu offers to send the crash report after a reboot, and you agree, then you have already done your part.

Comment: It doesn't offer to upload it.  But now I see there are two more files:  `_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload` and `_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded`.  The former is empty, the latter contains a UUID.

Does that mean it uploaded it?